# How to instantiate classes only from inside another class in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I need to prevent class A from being instantiated anywhere but only from another class B, then class B can return the created instance of class A which can be used in any other class.

I understand that B could be a Factory in this example, I looked in the factory pattern in the Haxe code cookbook but it does not seem suit what I am looking for.

In my example class B is doing some work then should return the result in an instance of class A.

no one should be able to create an instance of class A because it is the result of the work that class B performs. anyone needs an instance of A should ask B to do the work and return the resulted A instance

hope I explained it clearly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would usually do this by using [`@:allow()` metadata](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-access-control.html) in combination with a private constructor:

`A.hx`:

```
class A {
    @:allow(B)
    private function new() {}
}
```

`B.hx`:

```
class B {
    public static function create():A {
        return new A(); // compiles
    }
}
```

Trying to instantiate `A` outside of `B` will result in a compiler error:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        new A(); // Cannot access private constructor of A
    }
}
```

Note that it's still possible to work around this by using `@:access()` or `@:privateAccess` metadata - in Haxe, nothing is ever *truly* private. It follows a philosophy of "the programmer knows best", which can be very powerful.

Also, you might want to declare `A` as `@:final` so nothing can subclass it, because subclasses can access private fields in Haxe. But again, this can be overriden with `@:hack` metadata.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed and well explained answer, I will try this in my code. really very much appreciated